# How to rbind two data frames and convert as.mids?

Tags: r, r-mice

**AIM**: Convert a xlsx file into a as.mids object.

**PROBLEM**: Multiple imputation is performed in SAS resulting in two seperate data frames:

1. Original DF with missing data
2. Imputed DF with n imputation

**What have I tried so far?**:

1. Add a variable ".imp" to original DF and set to 0 (according to as.mids: value 0 indicates the original data (with missings))
2. Stack original data set on imputed DF (according to as.mids: "The original incomplete dataset needs to be available so that we know where the missing data are)

**CODE**:

```
install.packages('mice')  # install if not already installed
library(mice)
library(dplyr)

# create imputed data set
df <- structure(list(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4), 
                      time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                     .imp = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                     pain = c(15, 25, 30, 70, 71, 80, 82, 90, 100, 60, 70, 96, 15, 25, 30, 70, 68, 80, 85, 90, 100, 66, 70, 96),
                     weight = c(66, 68, 69, 74, 76, 78, 59, 65, 68, 65, 63, 70, 66, 68, 69, 74, 76, 80, 59, 65, 68, 69, 67, 70)), 
                .Names = c("id", "time", ".imp", "pain", "weight"), row.names = c(NA,-24L), class = "data.frame")

# create original data set with missing data
df_cc <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), 
                     time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                     .imp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     pain = c(15, 25, 30, 70, NA, 80, NA, 90, 100, NA, 70, 96),
                     weight = c(66, 68, 69, 74, 76, NA, 59, 65, 68, NA, NA, 70)), 
                .Names = c("id", "time", ".imp", "pain", "weight"), row.names = c(NA,-12L), class = "data.frame")
# stack data sets
df_full <- bind_rows(mutate(df, across(where(is.double), as.factor)), 
                     mutate(df_cc, across(where(is.double), as.factor)))
# order by .imp
df_full$.imp <- factor(df_full$.imp, levels = c(0, 1, 2))
df_full <- df_full[order(df_full$id, df_full$.imp),]

# convert to as.mids object
df_mids <- as.mids(df_full, .imp = ".imp", .id = "id")
```

This results in the error:

```
df_mids <- as.mids(df_full, .imp = ".imp", .id = "id")
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ‘4’
```

I cant seem to find a solution for this error on either stackoverfow or in the [mice package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf).

Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

You want the *m* imputed data sets in long format including the un-imputed version. You probably missed the `include=TRUE` argument in `complete()` and now are facing an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

This is how you can do it right:

```
X <- mice::mice(nhanes, print=FALSE)


mice::complete(X, action='long', include=TRUE)
#    .imp .id age  bmi hyp chl
# 1     0   1   1   NA  NA  NA
# 2     0   2   2 22.7   1 187
# 3     0   3   1   NA   1 187
# 4     0   4   3   NA  NA  NA
# 5     0   5   1 20.4   1 113
# 6     0   6   3   NA  NA 184
# 7     0   7   1 22.5   1 118
# 8     0   8   1 30.1   1 187
# 9     0   9   2 22.0   1 238
# 10    0  10   2   NA  NA  NA
# 11    0  11   1   NA  NA  NA
# 12    0  12   2   NA  NA  NA
# 13    0  13   3 21.7   1 206
# 14    0  14   2 28.7   2 204
# 15    1   1   1 30.1   1 204
# 16    1   2   2 22.7   1 187
# 17    1   3   1 21.7   1 187
# 18    1   4   3 21.7   1 204
# 19    1   5   1 20.4   1 113
# 20    1   6   3 22.0   1 184
# 21    1   7   1 22.5   1 118
# 22    1   8   1 30.1   1 187
# 23    1   9   2 22.0   1 238
# 24    1  10   2 22.7   1 118
# 25    1  11   1 22.5   1 238
# 26    1  12   2 22.0   1 187
# 27    1  13   3 21.7   1 206
# 28    1  14   2 28.7   2 204
# 29    2   1   1 20.4   1 187
# 30    2   2   2 22.7   1 187
# 31    2   3   1 28.7   1 187
# ...
```

**Anyway,** in OP your `id` and the mice `.id` columns are different sorts of things. The former is completely irrelevant for `mice`. The latter should be consecutively created for each .imp. You also won't need factors. Try this:

```
rdf <- rbind(df, df_cc) 

rdf[with(rdf, order(.imp, id)), ] |>
  transform(.id=ave(.imp, .imp, FUN=seq.int)) |>
  mice::as.mids()
# Class: mids
# Number of multiple imputations:  2 
# Imputation methods:
#     id   time   pain weight 
#     ""     ""  "pmm"  "pmm" 
# PredictorMatrix:
#        id time pain weight
# id      0    1    1      1
# time    1    0    1      1
# pain    1    1    0      1
# weight  1    1    1      0
```

Not exactly sure what you are doing, though, where you get separated data frames from, why you transform `NA` to `0`.

---

*Data:*

```
data('nhanes', package='mice')
nhanes <- nhanes[1:14, ]
```

Comment: Thank you. To answer your questions:
Where you get separated data frames from: The imputation is not performed in R. So its exported from SAS with the imputed data frame only. Why you transform NA to 0: I wasn't aware I was doing that. 

I can't get it to work: 

rdf[with(rdf, order(.imp, id)), ] |>
Error: unexpected '>' in "rdf[with(rdf, order(.imp, id)), ] |>"
transform(.id=ave(.imp, .imp, FUN=seq.int)) |>
Error: unexpected '>' in "  transform(.id=ave(.imp, .imp, FUN=seq.int)) |>"
mice::as.mids()
Error in .imp %in% names(long) : 
  argument "long" is missing, with no default